# When I console.log(portfoliosArray) it returns an array or four arrays?

Tags: arrays, json, object, handlebars.js, this

Instead of returning an array of objects, pulling from a JSON file, it returns an array of 4 arrays containing 4 objects? Why? JSON file name is portfolios.json.

```
'use strict';

var portfolioArray = [];

function Portfolio (portfoliosDataObj) {  
  this.title = portfoliosDataObj.title;  
  this.body = portfoliosDataObj.body;  
  this.img = portfoliosDataObj.img;  
}

Portfolio.prototype.toHtml = function() {  
  var renderPortfolios = Handlebars.compile($('#portfolio-template').text());  
  return renderPortfolios(this);  
  console.log(this);  
};

$.getJSON('/data/portfolios.json', function(portfolios) {  
  portfolios.forEach(function(portfoliosDataObject) {  
    var portfolio = new Portfolio(portfoliosDataObject);  
    portfolioArray.push(portfolios);  
    console.log(portfolios);  
  });  
});

function print () {  
  portfolioArray.forEach(function(data) {  
    $('#portfolioSection').append(data.toHtml());  
  });


}

Portfolio();   
print();
```

JSON FILE - Adding for reference.

```
[{
  "title": "CodeFellows/Code201",
  "body": "content1",
  "img": ""
},
{
  "title": "CodeFellows/Code301",
  "body": "lorem ipsum"
},
{
  "title": "Upcoming Projects/Other interest",
  "body": "lorem impsum",
  "img": "/images/blog.jpg"

},
{
  "title": "Illustrations",
  "body": "lorem ipsum",
  "img": "/images/portfolio.png"
}]
```

IGNORE need more content that isn't code to post....
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porttitor leo at tellus facilisis, id suscipit ipsum suscipit. Aenean venenatis, quam semper efficitur hendrerit, odio diam condimentum odio, id sagittis lorem tellus vel mauris. Cras enim neque, malesuada sit amet lacinia et, ullamcorper non sapien. Integer id hendrerit nulla, vitae tristique tortor. Aenean in arcu eget massa pulvinar dictum. Aliquam dictum fermentum sapien id iaculis. Ut malesuada varius lacinia. Maecenas scelerisque facilisis mattis.

Comment: Show us the content of the json file.

Comment: @gaganshera added file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file returns an array of 4 **objects**, and not arrays.

```
{
  "title": "CodeFellows/Code201",
  "body": "content1",
  "img": ""
}
```

is a javascript object, not an array (notice the curly braces {}).
The outer one is an array. (notice the square brackets[]).

You can get to the objects by doing a `console.log(portfolios[0]);`

Comment: yes but when I console.log(portfolioArray) it returns => [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)] each containing the four objects.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, do it like `console.log(portfolios[0]);`

Comment: Do the console.log right after you get the data, before the foreach loop.

Comment: Yes. The file returns 4 objects because that it contains 4 objects. My array however that I'm using to print to the page contains four separate arrays and will not print to page.

Comment: There's a typo in your foreach. `portfolioArray.push(portfolios );` should be `portfolioArray.push(portfolio);  `

Comment: Also, use the console.log outside the loop to see the `portfolioArray`

Comment: Thankyou! @gaganshera

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this code. You are pushing `portfolios` in `portfolioArray` instead of `portfolio`. Also you were doing `console.log` for portfolios which is why it was showing 4 arrays. I have fixed the code. Let me know if it works for you.

```
$.getJSON('/data/portfolios.json', function(portfolios) {  
  portfolios.forEach(function(portfoliosDataObject) {  
    var portfolio = new Portfolio(portfoliosDataObject);  
    portfolioArray.push(portfolio);  
    console.log(portfolio);  
  });  
});
```

Comment: Glad i could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted